# Update a part of 'data-content' of popover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to find a solution, I would like to update just a part of data-content of popover. Exemple of code:

```
<div class="popover-wrapper">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign hover_content"
                                           id="popover_help"
                                           data-toggle="popover"
                                           data-placement="right"
                                           data-content="<p>Some static text
                                                        <span class='update-text'>Dynamic text to update</span>
                                                        </p>"
                                           data-html="true">
                                        </i>
</div>
<button class="update-popover" onClick="updatePopoverContent()">Click to update</button>
<script>
    function updatePopoverContent() {
        $('.popover-wrapper .hover_content')???;//and something like attr(‘data-content .update-text’, ‘new text’)
    }
</script>
```

to show popover I use:

```
$(".hover_content").popover({
            trigger: "manual",
            animation: false,
            delay: {
                "hide": 30
            }
        }).on("mouseenter", function() {
            var _this = this;
            $(this).popover("show");
            $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
                $(_this).popover('hide');
            });
        }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            var _this = this;
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to change just a part of 'data-content' text? Maybe someone can give some advice? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you using to show the popover?  It's not [tag:jquery] out of the box.  *Probably* bootstrap, but please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bootstrap-4, you can update the attribute `data-content`.

**NB:** you cannot update the `.data` value using jquery's `.data("content", newValue)` as it appears the popper reads the attribute directly each time instead of honouring the data convention.

```
$("#popover_help").attr("data-content", replacementHtml);
```

To update just the `update-text` part, you can read the HTML, parse it, use jquery to change it, then write it back as HTML:

```
var html = $("#popover_help").data("content");
var parsed = $("<div/></div>").html(html);
parsed.find("span").text("Updated text");
$("#popover_help").attr("data-content", parsed.html());
```

You can apply this to a .class to update all if you have more than one, here's an example.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

function updatePopoverContent() {
    $(".hover_content").each(function() {
     var html = $(this).data("content");
     var parsed = $("<div/></div>").html(html);
     parsed.find("span").html("<strong>Updated</strong> text");
     $(this).attr("data-content", parsed.html());
     // doesn't update if currently shown, so hide then show if desired
     $(this).popover("hide");
     //$(this).popover("show");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<br/>
<div class="popover-wrapper">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign hover_content"
                                           id="popover_help"
                                           data-toggle="popover"
                                           data-placement="right"
                                           data-title="Example"
                                           data-content="<p>Some static text
                                                        <span class='update-text'>Dynamic text to update</span>
                                                        </p>"
                                           data-html="true">
                                           click me
                                        </i>
</div>
<hr/>
<button class="update-popover" onClick="updatePopoverContent()">Click to update</button>
```